# Selenium | Attach already opened browser(IE) to webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on automation of a website in which I need to perform some action using **user A** then **user B** needs to approve the same.

By default the web-application takes credentials from the windows login itself as there is no login page for this.

So What I did was, I automated all the actions from **user A**. Now to perform the action from **user B** ,I created a `.vbs` utility which I am calling in my java code, this utility opens a web browser and sign into the application with user B (I used shell scripting in vbs for this). Now I have two web browser one which is opened by webdriver (On which I performed some action with **User A**) and the other which has been opened by the vbs utility(I need to perform some action on this browser)   and since my second browser is not opened by Webdriver I am searching a way to attach it to webdriver so that I can perform some actions on it & approve the request created by **User A**.

**Additional Information:**
I need to perform this in IE since this is client requirement.
I am using java for selenium.

Comment: Why dont you open a new webdriver and instead on creating a vbs?

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, I believe that you are tackling your problem incorrectly. Since I cannot tell what sort of authentication you are dealing with in your browser, I suppose I can show you a form and HTTP 401, which will most likely cover the general scenarios. If you need some other example, for a different way to authenticate, do let us know.

If I have misread your request, and you actually want to hook onto a manually started instance of a browser, which is not provided by default, you have to get really creative. Regardless, that question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session).

However, as far as my recommendation goes, I would highly recommend that you get rid of that vb script / manual browser starting if possible. If you can authenticate through your browser, than you can do it through selenium. Here are some examples:

[Note, this is a good guide on how to use the InternetExplorerDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115474/how-can-i-start-internetexplorerdriver-using-selenium-webdriver)

Scenario 1: Using an HTML Form
Sample HTML Code:

```
<form>
    <table id="credentials_table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="credentials_table_label_cell"><label for="username" id="label_input_1">Username</label></td>
        <td class="credentials_table_field_cell"><input class="credentials_input_text" value="" id="username" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="credentials_table_label_cell"><label for="password" id="label_input_2">Password</label></td>
        <td class="credentials_table_field_cell"><input class="credentials_input_password" value="" id="password" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" type="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="submit_row">
        <td class="credentials_table_field_cell"><input class="credentials_input_submit" value="Logon" type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</form>
```

Sample Selenim Code to Login:

```
private WebDriver driverForA = new InternetExplorerDriver();
private WebDriver driverForB = new InternetExplorerDriver();

@After
public void after() {
    driverForA.close();
    driverForB.close();
}

@Test
public void testADoesThisAndBDoesThat() {

    driverForA.get("http://my.login.url");
    final WebElement usernameInput = driverForA.findElement(By.id("username"));
    final WebElement passwordInput = driverForA.findElement(By.id("password"));
    final WebElement submitButton = driverForA.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Logon']"));
    // perform the login stuff
    clearKeysAndSetValue(usernameInput, "Joe");
    clearKeysAndSetValue(passwordInput, "superSecret");
    submitButton.click();
    // navigate to other pages and do things

    driverForB.get("http://my.approval.page");
    final WebElement approveButton = driverForB.findElement(By.id("approval_Button"));
    approveButton.click();

}

private void clearKeysAndSetValue(final WebElement element, final String valueToSet) {
    element.clear();
    element.sendKeys(valueToSet);
}
```

[Scenario 2: Using HTTP 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

```
private final WebDriver driverForA = new InternetExplorerDriver();
private final WebDriver driverForB = new InternetExplorerDriver();

@After
public void after() {
    driverForA.close();
    driverForB.close();
}

@Test
public void testADoesThisAndBDoesThatHttpBasic() {
    // authenticate as a
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driverForA, 5);      
    Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
    alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("Joe", "superSecret"));
    // navigate to other pages and do things

    driverForB.get("http://my.approval.page");
    final WebElement approveButton = driverForB.findElement(By.id("approval_Button"));
    approveButton.click();
}
```